# Django AdZone and problem in the admin

Tags: django, django-admin

im would like to use the cool app Django-AdZone, i thinks is a nice work , but i have a litter problem:

i have 2 website, django-adzone is working very nice in one of those website, but in the second website is not working.

I cant see in the django admin the app adzone, i dont know why, i did the same steps for both website, and the second website is not showing the adzone in the admin, the settings.py are similar with relation to adzone.

Any idea?

thanks guys

sorry with my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, now i know where is the error, is not django , is python2.5, here is the error while install

```
return self.loader.get_data(path)
zipimport.ZipImportError: bad local file header in /home/bismark/lib/python2.5/d                jango_adzone-0.2-py2.5.egg
```

Comment: The problem was Django, i upgrade to Django 1.2.1 and is working now:)